# Autodesk Forge DiffTool extension for DWF

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, difftool

Based on the below article link, The Forge Viewer (7.36) makes it easy to load and view PDF and DWF files natively
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/dwf-and-pdf-support-forge-viewer

I am loading the 3D DWF files using the same procedure and wonder if the DiffTool Extension can show the differences in the models of the DWF files. Based on supported mimeType of the DiffTool, I have tried ‘application/vnd.autodesk.dxf’: For DXF and ‘application/vnd.autodesk.autocad.dwg’: For DWG. But it doesn't work. Please suggest if there is special mimeType supported for DWF files. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

We support only a range of file formats because some of the formats don't provide a never changing unique ID for objects. Basically if an object changes in a new version we need to identify it on that new version. If we don't have unique IDs then it's very difficult to identify the same objects.

This is the list from the code showing which type of models can be compared.

```
'application/vnd.autodesk.fusion360': { 'supports2d': true },
    'application/vnd.autodesk.f3d': { 'supports2d': true },
    'application/vnd.autodesk.revit': { 'supports2d': true },
    'application/vnd.autodesk.r360': { 'supports2d': true },
    'application/vnd.autodesk.inventor.assembly': { 'supports2d': true },
    'application/vnd.autodesk.navisworks': { 'supports2d': true  },
    'application/vnd.autodesk.cad': { 'supports2d': false  },
    'application/vnd.autodesk.dxf': { 'supports2d': false  },
    'application/vnd.autodesk.autocad.dwg': { 'supports2d': false  }
```